# Rolling mean and standard deviation without zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that one of its columns represents how many corns produced in this time stamp.
for example

```
timestamp corns_produced another_column
1           5                  4
2           0                  1
3           0                  3
4           3                  4
```

The dataframe is big.. 100,000+ rows

I want to calculate `moving average` and `std` for 1000 time stamps of `corn_produced`.
Luckily it is pretty easy using `rolling` :

- `my_df.rolling(1000).mean()`
- `my_df.rolling(1000).std()`.

But the problem is I want to ignore the zeros, meaning if in the last 1000 timestamps there are only 5 instances in which corn was produced, I want to do the `mean` and `std` on those 5 elements.

How do I ignore the zeros ?

Just to clarify, I don't want to do the following `x = my_df[my_df['corns_produced'] != 0]`, and than do `rolling` on `x`, because it ignores the time stamps and doesn't give me the result I need

Comment: Is possible use trick - replace `0` to `NaN`s like `my_df = my_df.replace(0, np.nan)` and then use `my_df.rolling(1000).mean()`, `my_df.rolling(1000).std()` ?

Comment: @jezrael , If it will give me the correct result, I can live with it.

Comment: is possible verify?

Comment: The item to check is if one or the other item is 0 do you want to include that time stamp.  If you do want to ignore it for the one that is 0 and use the other number then @jezrael trick will work.  If not then create a copy of the row drop the timestamps with either one is zero then work it out.  If you need an example just ask,

Comment: @jezrael I've tried it and it didn't provide the correct result. 
`x = pd.DataFrame({'bla' : [2,1,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,2,2,2]})`
`x = x.replace(0, np.nan)`
`x['mean'] = x['bla'].rolling(3).mean()`
If you want, run it and look on rows 4 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html):

```
print (my_df.rolling(1000).apply(lambda x: x[x!= 0].mean()))
print (my_df.rolling(1000).apply(lambda x: x[x!= 0].std()))
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution: first set all zeros to `np.nan`, then take a rolling mean. If you are dealing with large data, it will be much faster

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).